# Close and open an excel workbook without flickering

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have been trying to achieve this from my application level addin but some how not able to get this right. Below are the steps I am trying to achieve on click of an application level addin button:

1. Open an existing Excel file in current application.
2. Do some refresh.
3. After refresh close that (with Save = true)
4. Open the workbook again
5. Do some other stuff.

I have use Application.ScreenUpdating = false and Application.EnableAlerts = false before start of the above steps. But what is happening is that after step 3 the whole application just closes and then after step 5 it shows up again.

I also tried this:

1. Open an existing Excel file in current application.
2. Do some refresh.
3. Add a new blank workbook in the same application (additional step)
4. After refresh close that (with Save = true)
5. Open the workbook again
6. Do some other stuff.

IN this case as well the application closes from UI and appears after step 6. Till step 3 the screen just freezes (which is wanted)

This actually gives a very bad user experience. I want to stop the closing of UI when I close and re-open the workbook and just freeze the screen so that user sees the same UI that he saw when he clicked the button.

Is there anyway to achieve a seamless experience for the user (UI experience) so that the user does not see this flickering. Any approach would help.

**Why I want to do this :** I am trying to copy a Powerpivot model from one workbook to another. Somehow this works when done manually but throws error (Model corrupt) if done through VSTO. So, I figured out that after copy by code if I save, close and open the workbook, the model is fine. If there is a better solution to this issue then also it works for me.

- Girija

Comment: Does user need to see the refresh? If not, set a placeholder in the current application that informs user to stand by? That way user will only see the placeholder until everything is done.

Comment: @findwindow :  Sorry but could not get that. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @findwindow :  Do you mean I show some progress UI , so that the user sees that. I already have a progress window, but what happens is that the Progress windows is visible but behind the workbook closes and opens up. During the close the background is my desktop. This gives a very clumsy experience. BTW I am running the progress dialog in separate thread so that the UI experience is seamless - Girija

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but I have a master book that opens and closes 300+ books. The master provides a progress UI so that the user never sees the 300+ books getting opened and closed. Just the master/progress.

Comment: Ok got it because you keep the master as is and do not close it. The other workbooks apart from master are closed and opened. In my case imagine that I have to save, close and open the master itself. - Girija

Comment: So create a new "master" that merely serves as a placeholder? Not most efficient but not sure how you can preserve an image of excel when you completely close the app...

Comment: @findwindow : I do not completely close the application. The application remains alive and only the workbook is closed.